# Xamarin async Http Client

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin, httpclient

I've got a problem in my Xamarin Project: When I try to get a JsonString from a Webpage, via HttpClient.GetStringAsncy does my app crash. Here is the StackTrace of the error:

```
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__63.MoveNext () [0x00479] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__54.MoveNext () [0x0007d] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
  at MRKrauchthal.Pages.GameDetailPage+d__13.MoveNext () [0x00057] in E:\Visual Studio Projects\MRKrauchthal\MRKrauchthal\MRKrauchthal\Pages\GameDetailPage.xaml.cs:99
```

#### e.InnerException

```
{System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.) ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00037] in :0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in :0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00032] in :0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in :0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0004b] in :0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000e] in :0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x0000e] in :0 
  at Mono.Net.Security.MonoTlsStream.CreateStream (System.Byte[] buffer) [0x0007b] in :0 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.CreateStream (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x00073] in :0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00058] in :0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in :0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__63.MoveNext () [0x0041e] in :0 }
```

#### The Code looks like this:

```
private async Task SetImage(int id, string teamName, Xamarin.Forms.Image image)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonImage>(await httpClient.GetStringAsync("www.linkToImage.com").ConfigureAwait(false));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            test.Text = e.StackTrace;
        }

    }
```

I hope someone can help me :D

Best Regards

Comment: You're printing the stack trace but not the error message. Please add that information since it's probably the key to resolve the problem

Comment: What happens if your `GET` returns an error?  You dont check if the result is successful before trying to deserialize.  Just because you _can_ write it on one line, does not mean you _should_.

Comment: The error message I get with e.message is: An error occurred while sending the request

Comment: When I try the link at my own, by copy pasting the link in my browser i get a full json respond

Comment: The exception thrown is most likely an `AggregateException`. It's property `InnerExceptions` contains the real exceptions which where thrown. Can you share those please?

Comment: @NtFreX i've added the innerexception to my question.

Comment: Try changing your url to `https://www.linkToImage.com`. Maybe it helps

Comment: @NtFreX the url already starts with "https" -> original link: "https://api-v2.swissunihockey.ch/api/teams/428351"

Comment: I mean the string you are using in the `GetStringAsync` method.

Comment: @NtFreX string: `"https://api-v2.swissunihockey.ch/api/teams/428351"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some problem with the default SSL/TLS implementation in Xamarin.Android. You can go to Android **Project settings->Android Options->Advanced->SSL/TLS implementation** and change to **Native TLS 1.2+**
[image]